# Remove duplicate sentence by comparing two strings with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I want to write an algorithm in `ruby` that returns `true` if the sentence can be deleted and returns `false` if it cannot.

For example:
string_that_can_be_deleted = `Where is my key?`
by = `Where is my`

In this case, the `string` should not be deleted because `by` is not a complete sentence.

#### My progress till now

```rb
def deletable?(string, by:)
  return false if string.length == by.length

  arr = by.split.map(&:downcase).map do |word|
    string.downcase.scan(word)
  end.flatten

  if string.length > by.length
    string.split.map(&:downcase).all? { |ele| arr.include?(ele) }
  else
    arr.all? { |ele| by.split.map(&:downcase).include?(ele) }
  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
deletable?("Where is my key?", by: "Where is my")

=> false
```

Here are a couple of test cases:

```rb
string_that_can_be_deleted = `Where`
by = `Where is Finland`

=> true
```

```rb
string_that_can_be_deleted = `Howis my friend` # not a typo
by = `How is my friend, just asking`

=> true
```

```rb
string_that_can_be_deleted = `Is it raining outside?`
by = `Is it raining inside?`

=> false
```

```rb
string_that_can_be_deleted = `tunisia is good`
by = `tunisia is cool, but ok`

=> false
```

With my current implementation except for the last, everything passes.

Comment: These quotation marks are not what you think they are. They are backticks, and ruby asks windows or Linux or whatever to execute anything inside them. Possibly very dangerous.

Comment: Yes, just made a typo while pasting the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem just requires to strip all non letter characters and check if `by` starts with `string`. This code worked for all of your test cases

```rb
def deletable?(string, by:)
  clean_str = string.delete("^a-zA-Z")
  clean_by = by.delete("^a-zA-Z")
  clean_by.start_with?(clean_str)
end
```

Bonus: it might be good to downcase all characters so comparison is not case sensitive.

Comment: How to do this for every character. Like numbers, words, punctuations, etc?

Comment: You can change regex to only get rid of chars that should be ignored. If you requirement is to keep numbers and punctuation, and only get rid of white space, then use `delete("\s")`